# "i18next: missingKey" whilst using 'react-i18next' and 'react-router-dom'

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, i18next, react-i18next

I'm working on a React-app in which I'd like to use i18next. To do so, I've added `i18next` and `react-i18next` to my app and everything seems to work like a charm.

My app uses the `BrowserRouter` from [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) to switch between various views. When I load the root URL at http://localhost:3000, everything runs like a charm. I can switch pages, which are then translated without any problem. The `BrowserRouter` pushes URL changes to the browser history so users can use the Back- and Forward-buttons in their browser to navigate. This means that once a user clicks one of the menu items in the app, the URL changes, i.e. from http://localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3000/suppliers.

If I hit refresh after such a change though, a problem occurs: the console shows `i18next::translator: missingKey undefined translation` and the view is not translated. The same behavior is shown when a redirect from the root URL to a default page is added. The strange thing is that the entire app's root UI (headerbar, sidebar) is translated, it's only the part of the page that is managed by react-router (every component nested within the relevant `<Route>`) that shows untranslated. This is also only the fact on browser load, so after a full page refresh or after an initial navigation to the page. If I navigate in my app after loading, even navigating to the same view, the translated view is shown instead.

I wrapped everything within my `<App>`-component in a `<Suspense>`-block, including the `<BrowserRouter>`, but the problem still occurs. My JSX-structure looks somewhat like this:

```
<App>
    <Suspense fallback={<Loader /}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <SideMenu>
                {/* Translated objects are shown here */}
            </SideMenu>
            <HeaderBar>
                {/* Translated objects are shown here as well */}
            </HeaderBar>
            <Views>
                <Route path="/sample" component={SampleComponent} /> {/* SampleComponent will not be translated after changing language or navigating to `/sample` immediately/by refreshing` */}
            </Views>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Suspense>
</App>
```

I'm using a very simple configuration:

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'nl',
    debug: true,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false
    }
  });

export default i18n;
```

I found an older issue on GitHub (https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/322) without a clear solution and for an older version of react-i18next. I'm not entirely sure how to integrate react-router with react-i18next to prevent this behavior.

**Edit** another strange thing is the fact that a call to `i18n.changeLanguage` is propagated to every view except the components nested within the `<Route>`... I think it might be related but I've still been unable to find a solution...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found an actual solution for the situation I described, but based on the documentation for the [Trans](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component) component I switched my views to using `t` instead of `Trans` and they started working. As I need no complex formatting for my translated strings this is a nice solution. Another solution would be to wrap a component that needs Trans in the HOC-solution, which seems to work as well.